# Prolog appending list

Tags: prolog

I have an issue with appending list.

```
find_paths(Start, Finish) :- path(Start, Finish, [Start], Path), 
                             append([Path], List, Result), 
                             fail.
```

Path is a list.

I will get n paths for the fail, 
but if i put write(Result), it will print this [[...], H234] n times.

How to tell prolog to use back the result from the last iteration and append together with
a new path for every fail?

Comment: please add some information about what you got and what you want

Comment: nvm . i think i got it . i use setoff, so it returns all solution as a list.

Answer (score 2):

The variable List is free, so unsurprisingly the result of appending a path ([...]) to a variable (H234) is printed. The simplest way to improve your code would be

```
find_paths(Start, Finish, List) :- 
       findall(Path, path(Start, Finish, [Start], Path), List).
```

Alternatively, you can change the definition of path/4 to accumulate the results.